# Cron removing $ character from environment variable in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, cron, environment-variables

I have an environment variable in a docker container that stores a password with special characters. This particular password contains a $ in it. I output this environment variable in a shell script. If I run the script manually, everything is fine. When the cron runs the script, the $ and the following 2 characters are removed. I have tried escaping the special characters in several ways, the latest of which is below, but the outcome is the same (fine manually, missing with the cron). For this example, assume the password is **blahblah$xy*blahblah**, which is what I would see when running the script. If the cron runs the script, I would get **blahblah*blahblah**.

My script (testVars.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Testing variables"

MY_PASS=$MY_PASSWORD
TEST_PASS=$(sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9,._+@%/-]/\\&/g; 1{$s/^$/""/}; 1!s/^/"/; $!s/$/"/' <<< $MY_PASSWORD)

echo ${MY_PASS}
echo ${TEST_PASS}
```

My cron:

```
BASH_ENV=/root/env_vars.sh
33 13 * * * root /opt/testVars.sh >> /opt/cron.log
```

I am assuming that it is actually possible to have a $ sign in a string in this way.

Comment: $MY_PASSWORD` is an environment variable containing your password?

Comment: Are you setting MY_PASSWORD in /root/env_vars.sh? If so, how? Notice that that file is itself a shell script, so any occurrences of special characters need to be protected.

Comment: @Nic3500 Yes, that's correct

Comment: @TurePålsson Actually the password is contained in a secret as part of the deployment. It's exported, along with other variables, when the pod starts using the following command within docker-entrypoint.sh:

`printenv | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/export \1/g' > /root/env_vars.sh`

I did wonder if the variable was being altered prior to testVars.sh executing, but if that were the case I'd expect manually running testVars.sh to also display the password incorrectly, unless it's a cron thing that changes it initially.

Comment: But if your `printenv` is anything like that on my Mac, that means that /root/env_vars.sh contains something like `MY_PASSWORD=foo$bar*fie`? That won’t work, because `$foo` will be interpreted as a variable expansion.

Comment: @TurePålsson Ahh ok, yes my env_vars.sh file contains `MY_PASSWORD=blahblah$xy*blahblah`. Which means $xy is being interpreted as a variable expansion then? So would I then need to wrap the password in double quotes to protect it, or is there a better way?

Comment: To be honest, I’m not sure what the best solution is. Double quotes won’t work, because variable expansion still happens inside them. Single quotes might, but will obviously break if the password has a single quote in it. Perhaps extend that `sed` command to put backslashes before any "dangerous" character, but  that sed expression won’t be pretty... Perhaps just write the password into a file and `read` from it? Probably depends on what the rest of the set-up looks like...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by added the following into the `docker-entrypoint.sh` file, just before my `printenv` command:

`export MY_PASSWORD=$(sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9,._+@%/-]/\\&/g; 1{$s/^$/""/}; 1!s/^/"/; $!s/$/"/' <<<"$MY_PASSWORD")`

Thanks to Ture Pålsson for pointing me in the right direction.